# Casl Vue set ability on reload + in router + after login based on role from async get request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, casl

Perhaps I am overlooking something very easy, but I have been looking at this for two days now and I cannot figure it out.

I have an Vue application where I would like to specify what a user can see or where he can go to based on his role. I am using casl-vue for this.

There are two moments I want to set the ability, on loading of the page and after login.

**On page load**

All works fine when I register the abilities with a synchronous function, like so:

main.js

```
import { abilitiesPlugin } from '@casl/vue';
import ability from '../config/ability';
Vue.use(abilitiesPlugin, ability);
```

ability.js

```
import { AbilityBuilder, Ability } from '@casl/ability';

export default AbilityBuilder.define((can, cannot) => {
  const role = 'Admin';

  switch (role) {
    case 'Admin':
      can('manage', 'all');
      break;
    case 'Author':
      can('manage', 'all');
      cannot('manage', 'users');
      break;
    case 'Trainer':
      break;
    case 'Participant':
      cannot('manage', 'all');
      break;
    default:
      cannot('manage', 'all');
  };
})
```

However, when I want to get the role using a function that returns a promise (getCurrentUserRole()), and therefore make the function async like so:

ability.js

```
export default AbilityBuilder.define(async (can, cannot) => {
  const role = await getCurrentUserRole();

  switch (role) {
    case 'Admin':
      can('manage', 'all');
      break;
    ...
    default:
      cannot('manage', 'all');
  };
})
```

I receive the following error:

> "TypeError: ability.on is not a function"

**After login**

Thankfully, updating the ability rules after login works using this.$ability.update:

```
const { role } = await someSignInFunction();
this.$ability.update(defineRulesFor(role));
this.$router.push({ name: 'home' });
```

However, it seems I cannot use this function on page load, because when I put it in App.vue (for example, in `beforeCreate()` or `created()`) the page is already loaded before I call ability.update, therefore the ability is updated 'too late'.

**Vue router**

I would also like to access the ability can method in my Vue Router instance (to control the routes my users can visit), but how do I get access to the ability instance in my router file?

If in any case my problem is not explained well, please let me know!

I am very grateful if anyone can help me with the setup structure.

Dependencies:

```
casl/ability: ^3.3.0
casl/vue: ^0.5.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that if you pass `async` function inside `AbilityBuilder.define` then `AbilityBuilder.define` returns a `Promise`. It can't magically make async code to be sync :)

So, what you need to do is to create a separate function `defineRulesFor(role)`:

```js
// src/config/rules.js

import { AbilityBuilder } from '@casl/ability'

export default function defineRulesFor(role) {
  const { can } = AbilityBuilder.extract()

  switch (role) {
    case 'Admin':
      can('manage', 'all');
      break;
    case 'Author':
      can('manage', 'all');
      cannot('manage', 'users');
      break;
    case 'Trainer':
      break;
    case 'Participant':
      cannot('manage', 'all');
      break;
    default:
      cannot('manage', 'all');
  }
}
```

Then after login:

```js
// inside Login.vue
import defineRulesFor from '../config/rules'

export default {
  name: 'LoginPage',
  methods: {
    async login() {
      const response = await axios.post(...)
      const user = response.data
      this.$ability.update(defineRulesFor(user.role))
    }
  }
}
```

And now you have 2 options:

1. Store user role in local storage and restore it on page reload:

```js
// inside App.vue

import defineRulesFor from './config/rules'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  created() {
    this.$ability.update(defineRulesFor(localStorage.getItem('userRole'))
  }
}
```

2. Refetch information about user on page reload

```js
// inside App.vue

import defineRulesFor from './config/rules'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  async created() {
    const role = await getCurrentUserRole()
    this.$ability.update(defineRulesFor(role))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Sergii Stotskyi ! I think in the end I got this far, but I still wonder how I will handle this in the router? In the router.beforeEach() I would like to check whether a user can access the route.

Also, just to confirm, the above ```defineRulesFor``` function should have ```const { can, cannot, rules } = AbilityBuilder.extract()``` and ```return rules``` right?

Comment: Yes, you need to return rules. About router check this comment - https://medium.com/@sergiy.stotskiy/so-there-are-several-approaches-3ee962fb9fb5

Comment: Is this still applicable to CASL version 5 ?

Comment: @stevebaros yes

Comment: i dont think so , because the  AbilityBuilder.extract()  function is removed

Comment: Just use the new way for creating AbilityBuilder. The concept is the same